# mouseWheel event not working Safari canvas

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, mousewheel

I am trying to handle `mouseWheel` event on Safari.
Below you can see my full functional example hmtl5/js code, to test the `mouseWheel` event.

My code trace a rectangle at each `mouseWheel` event and the wheel event is caught to define the size of the rectangle.

My problem is my code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox browser. But when it is tested on Safari browser event of wheel are not linear caught. In fact on Safari the event is called one time and after that there are no other wheel event sent.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("mon_canvas");
         var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
         ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
         ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
         var width = c.width;
         var height = c.height;
        
         var sizeRect = 100.0;
      drawRect(width/2 - sizeRect/2,height/2 - sizeRect/2,sizeRect ,sizeRect,'red');
      
      c.addEventListener('mousewheel',function(event){
         zoom(event);
      }); 
      c.addEventListener('Wheel',function(event){
         zoom(event);
      });   
      function zoom(event){
       if( event.deltaY > 0 ) sizeRect -= 10;
          if( event.deltaY <= 0 )sizeRect += 10;
       drawRect(0,0,width,height,'white');
       drawRect(width/2 - sizeRect/2,height/2 - sizeRect/2,sizeRect ,sizeRect,'red');
      }
      function drawRect(px,py,sizeX,sizeY,color){
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.rect(px,py ,sizeX,sizeY);
       ctx.fillStyle = color;
       ctx.fill(); 
      }
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

```html
<canvas id="mon_canvas" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Apple mice don't have wheels. ;-)

Comment: You right, I tested with magic mouse and trackpad. I think it's the same declaration of event.

Comment: Yes, I meant it as a joke. The ";-)" is an [old-skool emoji](https://xkcd.com/1953/).

Comment: It's my first post or anyone propose an answer

Comment: Good job on the first post. I've turned your code into a snippet, maybe it attracts some more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to delete wheel on browser and alway catch event.

```
window.onwheel = function(){ return false; }
```